# Installing a brew cask didn't require password, but uninstalling it does?

Tags: macos, installation

I meant to install [iStats](https://github.com/Chris911/iStats) but accidentally installed a different program that goes by a [similar name](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/istat-menus).

Naturally, I tried to uninstall program, but when I run

```
brew uninstall --cask istat-menus
==> Uninstalling Cask istat-menus
==> Removing launchctl service com.bjango.istatmenus.agent
Password:
```

it requires my computer's password, which I find odd (it didn't require a password to install the program, but it requires it to *un*install it).

Is it expected that

```
brew uninstall --cask <program>
```

would ask for a password? I found an instance of something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73596191/5783745), but not much else about this.

Comment: The `Removing launchctl service com.bjango.istatmenus.agent` seems to be the issue. How long between the time you installed it and decided to uninstall it? It might simply be an issue where removing a `launchctl` item needs a password, but installing doesn’t?

Comment: Only about 2 or 3 minutes passed between installing and realising I had the wrong software and needed to uninstall (probably 5 minutes total).

Comment: Okay, that seems odd. But honestly sometimes I am baffled why macOS requests an admin password at times for other things as well. Hopefully someone will have an answer they wish to share.